# Windows 10 System Alert Sound

Tags: windows-10, alert

I have a custom built pc. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and am occasionally getting a loud alert tone, steady but loud, like a thermal alert. I've run a hardware monitor and see the CPU core temps around 60C, with the motherboard alert set to 80C.

The sound appears to come from the system board and will happen once every few weeks.

Any ideas on how to determine what is causing this?

MB: Gigabyte X58A-UD3R
CPU: i7-930
RAM: 6x8GB

Anything else needed?

Comment: record the sound and upload somewhere we can listen or download it.

Comment: I can try, but it randomly occurs. It's a steady tone, like a single note from the speakers.

Comment: Does the sound come out of the speakers or from the system board?

Comment: I think the system board. I'd like to have it reoccur to tell you, but I'm hoping it won't. Edited the initial post.